# ODP.NET Database Change Notifications in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, odp.net

I wrote a console application in C# that uses ODP.NET to listen to database change notifications from an Oracle database. The console application works perfectly. I wrote a Windows service with the same code, but in the Windows service `OracleDependency.OnChange` is never firing.

Here is the code I am using to register for a database change notification:

```
string sql = GenerateQuery();
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    // Register a listener for the database change notification event
    OracleDependency dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
    dep.OnChange += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // Do stuff..
        };
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I can see the notification in the database by querying the `user_change_notification_regs` table, but the client never receives the callback. Again, in the console application version (with the same code), the client receives the callback perfectly.

The Windows service is running as a Network Service. I have also tried Local System, and neither appear to be working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the handler is not invoked? Do you do logging or do you deduct from the absence of side-effects that there's no invocation? Is any exception being caught somewhere that might be swallowed? Does the event log say anything about ASP.NET errors?

Comment: Try running the Service in the same account where you can run it as a console application normally.

Comment: @grim - I'm attaching VS's debugger to the service process after it starts up and putting a breakpoint on the first line of the handler. The breakpoint is never hit. VS is configured to stop on all exceptions, and the event log doesn't show anything useful.

Comment: @core - looks like that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service needed an exception in Windows Firewall. It worked flawlessly after adding the exception.